# Setting dynamic properties for Node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Assume a Node "Properties". I am using "LOAD CSV with headers..."
Following is the sample file format:

```
fields    
a=100,b=110,c=120,d=500
```

How do I convert fields column to having a node with a,b,c,d and 100,110,120,500 respectively as the properties of the node "Properties"?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/sample.tsv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' 
CREATE (:Properties {props: row.fields})
```

The above does not create individual properties, but sets a string value to props as "a=100,b=110,c=120,d=500"

Also, different rows could have different set of Key values. That is the key needs to be dynamic. (There are other columns as well, I trimmed it for SO)

```
fields
a=100,b=110,c=120,d=500
X=300,y=210,Z=420,P=600
...
```

I am looking for a way to not split this key-value as columns and then load. The reason is they are dynamic - today it is a,b,c,d it may change to aa,bb,cc,dd etc.
I don't want to keep on changing my loader script to recognize new column headers.

Any pointers to solve this? I am using the latest 3.0.1 neo4j version.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: Your file format currently defines a single header/property: `fields`:

```
fields    
a=100,b=110,c=120,d=500
```

Since you defined a tab as field terminator, that entire string (`a=100,b=110,c=120,d=500`) would end up in your node's `props` property:

[image: props as single property]

To have properties loaded dynamically: First set up proper header:

```
"a","b","x","y"
1,2,,
,,3,4
```

Then you can query with something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Users/David/overflow.csv' AS row
CREATE (:StackOverflow { a:row.a, b:row.b,x:row.x,y:row.y})
```

Then when you run something like:

```
match(so:StackOverflow) return so
```

You'll get the variable properties you wanted:

[image: variable properties]

Comment: I always have that option, however the problem is a bit different since there are quite a lot of such keys for "fields" column a,b,c,d,e,f,g....and in the future. keys in the fields column can change as well i.e from a,b,c,d to x,y,z. I can't keep on changing my CSV loader. I am looking for a flexible way of setting those key-value in "fields" as properties of a node.

Comment: I edited the question as well for more clarity. Thank you for the response.

Comment: If that's the case, I think you're going to end up building your own loader to parse the CSV. The built-in loader isn't designed for that.